# The page uses an invalid setting page

Tags: master-page, page-layout, html

I want to modify the layout of my page Index.aspx.

I adapt the html code with my change and i deploy the change on my sharepoint server. The problem was, i cannot the change. There was only the old page layout.

On a forum i found a code that can "apply" the change but the code crashed my application.

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb("mywebsite")
$spFile = $spWeb.GetFile("mywebsite/Pages/Index.aspx") 
$spFile.CheckOut("Online",$null) 
$spFile.Properties["PublishingPageLayout"] = "/_catalogs/masterpage/Pages/Index.aspx, Index" 
$spFile.Update() 
$spFile.CheckIn("Update page layout via PowerShell",[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::MajorCheckIn) 
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

How can i rollback the change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post has a slightly different method for changing the page layout that might work for you: http://myspworld.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/powershell-script-to-change-the-page-layout/

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb("http://yourwebapplication.com/yoursite")
$pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($spWeb)
$pSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite($spWeb.Site);

$siteLayouts = $pSite.GetPageLayouts($false)
$myLayout = $siteLayouts["/_catalogs/masterpage/yourpagelayout.aspx"]
#$myLayout
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'"

$pages = $pWeb.GetPublishingPages($query)

foreach ($page in $pages)
{
    if ($page.ContentType.Name -eq "Folder")
    {
        continue
    }

    $page.Layout = $myLayout
    $page.update()
    $page.ListItem.File.Publish("")
    $page.ListItem.File.Approve("")
}
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Comment: It work. I can see my Index.aspx page !